# How do I get the default fill values?

Tags: python, netcdf4

How can I get the default fill values using netcdf4-python?  According to [this issue](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python/issues/94) one can get it via `netCDF4._default_fillvals`, but this gives `AttributeError: module 'netCDF4' has no attribute '_default_fillvals'` 1.5.0.1.  The information is available somewhere, because `print(v)` tells me `filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used`.  Unfortunately the file has not set the fill value attribute.  Short of parsing the output of `v.__repr__()`, how can I find the default fill value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented in a parenthetical remark in the [documentation for `Dataset.create_variable`](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#Dataset.createVariable)

From the Changelog for [version 0.9.7](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python/blob/master/Changelog#L852):

> `* changed netCDF4._default_fillvals to netCDF4.default_fillvals (to make part of public API). Added to docs (issue 94).`

From the [documentation](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html) for the `Dataset.create_variable` static method:

> The optional keyword `fill_value` can be used to override the default netCDF `_FillValue` (the value that the variable gets filled with before any data is written to it, defaults given in `netCDF4.default_fillvals`). If `fill_value` is set to False, then the variable is not pre-filled.

This was fixed in [commit 36f6544b10f791f31c3a0911ea97351e03490c75](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python/commit/36f6544b10f791f31c3a0911ea97351e03490c75).